# Express/Node Behind AWS ELB - Can't Get Remote IP

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-elb

I know there are several posts about this but nothing I have tried works so I am wondering if those posts are just outdated.

Here's what I have tried in my Express Wrapper (with only one of them at a time obviously):

```
apiInstance.set('trust proxy', 1);
apiInstance.set('trust proxy', 2);
```

From there I was under the impression that calling req.ip would give me the remote IP of the client but low and behold I am still getting the IP of the load balancer.

I also tried referencing the headers ['x-forwarded-for'] but they are always undefined.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Express v4.13.

Comment: ELB Classic, ALB, or NLB?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Classic, it was spun up in 2014 and I *think* that's all that was available at that time.

Comment: Is the listener on the balancer in HTTP/HTTPS mode, or TCP mode? Is this a new problem, or is this just the first time it's being discovered?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot TCP on 443/80.  Existing problem that was just discovered.

Comment: TCP is the problem -- part of the problem.  ELB Classic can only inject the headers on HTTP/S listeners... but it may not be as simple as using a different balancer configuration.  Things like websockets and HTML EventSource don't work on a classic balancer in HTTP/S mode, so it's important to be sure you understand exactly what your platform does that might have prompted that configuration.  Classic balancers can use an alternste mechanism, called the "`PROXY` Protocol," to identify the source address, but this requires your back-ends also support the `PROXY` Protocol.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot That is great information.  The reason we have TCP on that is because of what you mentioned, websockets. I will continue to investigate further as I have to believe there must be some way to get this info.

Comment: @NicholasKreidberg you can use websockets if you switch to ALB and use HTTP/S instead of TCP.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande That's great information, thank you!